# Get column in datetime format and check if value is in it

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Basically, I have a pandas dataframe where a column is a string of dates. I want to transform each value into datetime so I can look for a specific value there later, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATESTAMP': ['01/01/2017','02/01/2017','03/01/2017']})

df['DATESTAMP2']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATESTAMP'])

date = datetime.strptime('02/01/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')

date in df['DATESTAMP2']
False
```

As you can see, it doesn't detect the date. I checked why, and I found that the format of the new `DATESTAMP2` column is

```
    df['DATESTAMP2']
Out[296]: 
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-02
2   2017-01-03
Name: DATESTAMP2, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['DATESTAMP2'][2]
Out[279]: Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00')
```

This is not datetime, it's a timestamp, which makes sense that it wouldn't be able to compare it with the `date` var.

Is there a way to solve this, aka to *actually* convert the column to datetime and not timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your dates are in two different formats (mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy)
2. The `in` operator isn't doing what you expect. It looks at index not values. Usually you just use `.values`, but for dates that doesn't usually work so you need to use `to_list()`.

Here is the two changes in context. Note addition of the format in to `to_datetime()` to deal with 1) and the `to_list()` to deal with 2)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATESTAMP': ['01/01/2017','02/01/2017','03/01/2017']})

df['DATESTAMP2']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATESTAMP'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

date = datetime.strptime('02/01/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')

print(date in df['DATESTAMP2'].to_list())
```

The timestamp vs datetime thing is not an issue. From [Timestamp Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is
> interchangeable with it in most cases.